# Single-use Class Idiom?

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns, idioms

There are times when you want to execute logic on some data once and only once per instance of that data. To my knowledge there is no such pattern (let alone idiom) for accomplishing this.

There is the `std::call_once()` but that only ensures something is executed once per process instance. Even if the `std::once_flag` could be used as a class data member it would simply ensure the function is only called once at runtime rather than trying to enforce it at compile time.

Enter the Single-use class:

```
class single_use_key {
public:
  single_use_key() : _self(new model_t()) {}
private:
  struct model_t {
    // Data you want used once and only once
  };

  std::unique_ptr<const model_t> _self;
};

class consumer_object {
public:
  consumer_object(single_use_key key) : _self(std::make_shared<const model_t>(std::move(key))) {}
private:
  struct model_t {
    model_t(single_use_key key) : _key(std::move(key)) {}
    ~model_t() {
      // Logic you want executed only once for the data
    }
    single_use_key _key;
  };

  std::shared_ptr<const model_t> _self;
};

single_use_key key;
consumer_object consumer(key); // Error
consumer_object consumer(std::move(key)); // OK
```

This idiom ensures that the class instance is used only once since it can only be moved and not copied.

If you wanted to try and use the object more than once you would have to reference it after you promised you would not (since `std::move()` was called). Even if you did this, the consumer class/function could be setup to ignore it just like how `std::call_once()` does because `std::unique_ptr<>` is guaranteed to be nulled after `std::move()`.

Do you see any problems with this idiom? Is there already something like this that I simply have not found yet? (Or perhaps I am stating something so obvious no one has ever bothered to document it...)

Comment: It seems like a rather complicated way to wrap up `std::unique_ptr`, since that's effectively all you're using to ensure single-use.  Why not just design your interface with direct use of `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @paddy I like to ensure value semantics while not having to check if the std::unique_ptr is null.

Comment: Wrapping the `std::unique_ptr` also achieves data hiding and allows friend or member functions to be added that **are** allowed to be called more than once.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how this ensures the "logic on some data" is executed once.  What "logic" are you referring to? It seems like this ensures some data is non-copyable which is something else.

Comment: @ChrisDrew It can be achieved any number of ways in the design of the consumer_object. I do via RAII and put the logic in the destructor of the consumer_object. I will update the post to reflect this.